# Substitute for tkinter.dooneevent

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am porting a program (VMD, Visual Molecular Dynamics), which is written in C++ and has both Python and TCL interpreters embedded, to Python 3.x. Most of its UI is hard coded using the TCL/TK framework and OpenGl, so UI refreshs are done manually. When the Python interpreter is running it is possible to dynamically create new windows and even add new menus to the main UI using Tkinter. In this case all TK events are flushed by periodically calling some code in the Python side (see below). This ensures that all updates are thread-safe and don't break the interpreter.

```
int PythonTextInterp::doTkUpdate() {
    // Don't recursively call into dooneevent - it makes Tkinter crash for
    // some infathomable reason.
    if (in_tk) return 0;
    if (have_tkinter) {
        in_tk = 1;
        int rc = evalString(
          "import Tkinter\n"
          "while Tkinter.tkinter.dooneevent(Tkinter.tkinter.DONT_WAIT):\n"
          "    pass\n"
        );
        in_tk = 0;
        if (rc) {
            return 1; // success
        }
        // give up
        have_tkinter = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However the function `tkinter.dooneevent` was removed from Python 3 and I can not find a substitute for it. I tried calling the low-level `Tcl_DoOneEvent(TCL_DONT_WAIT)` but when I dynamically created a new window I ended up crashing the Python interpreter with the error `Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate`.

The answers in [tkinter woes when porting 2.x code to 3.x, 'tkinter' module attribute doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714229/tkinter-woes-when-porting-2-x-code-to-3-x-tkinter-module-attribute-doesnt-ex/7714643#7714643) doesn't help since I don't have a list of all windows that may created by the user.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to flush the TK events in this case? It could be either on the Python side or in C++.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Rather than flush all the events (on the Python side) could you use the tkinter universal widget method `after_idle(<func>, *args)` to let it tell you when the system is idle and not processing any more events?

Comment: @martineau The problem is that the UI is constructed using only C++/TCL/TK so I don't have any widget available in Python to call its `after_idle`. Also the program doesn't allow calling `mainloop` from within any Python script, otherwise it stops responding.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this is equivalent:

```
root = tkinter.Tk()

# Here's your event handler. Put it in a loop somewhere.
root.tk.dooneevent(tkinter._tkinter.DONT_WAIT)
# I don't know if it's possible to access this method without a Tk object.
```

Now, I don't know how exactly to convert this into your code- do you have a root Tk object with which you can access `dooneevent`? I'm not at all familiar with python 2 tkinter so I don't know exactly how evenly my code maps to yours. However, I discovered this when I was doing something very similar to you- trying to integrate the `tkinter` event loop into the `asyncio` event loop. I was able to create a coroutine that calls this method in a loop, yielding each time (and sleeping occasionally), so that the GUI remains responsive without blocking the asyncio event loop with `tkinter._tkinter.create()`.

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def update_root(root):
    while root.tk.dooneevent(tkinter._tkinter.DONT_WAIT):
        yield
```

EDIT: I just read your comment about not having a widget. I know that the `root.tk` object is a `tkinter._tkinter.TkappType` instance created by calling `tkinter._tkinter.create`, and I don't think it's global. I'm pretty sure it's the core Tcl interpreter. You might be able to create your own by calling `create`. While it isn't documented, you can look at its usage in `tkinter.Tk.__init__`